# Aggregate by multiple fields and Top 10 questions and answers count in ElasticSearcch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-aggregation

When we execute the records for the few records only questions is coming and it is not showing up the answer against each question In the database we have answers for all the questions. Please let me know the query to get the both questions and answers for top 10 records. Below is the error.

**GET logstash-sdc-questionrecords/_search?q=source:website_portal**

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "genres": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "question.keyword",
        "order": {
          "_count": "desc"
        },
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "genres": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "answer.keyword",
            "order": {
              "_count": "desc"
            },
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bygju.png)

Comment: there is no error message in your question and screenshot, could u pls add it also add your mapping, sample and expected data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understand from your question is that you need to show top 10 questions with their answers, in order to achieve that you need to use the sub-aggregation and [top-hits will solve your use-case](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation), while currently you are using two different top level terms aggregation.

Your search query should look like below

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "genres": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "question.keyword",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_answer_hits": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "_source": {
              "includes": [
                "answer"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your quick help.  Must _not (Answer = "UNHANDLED") & Must (Source = "Sonax") This conditions also need to incorporate in this Above mentioned query. How to do it